# How to print the list of packages installed on TeX Live to a file?

Tags: packages, texlive

OS: Ubuntu 11.10
TeX: Tex Live 2011
[List of packages originally installed with Tex Live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28606/list-of-packages-originally-installed-with-tex-live)

Using the information given at the aforementioned question, I was able to see the list of packages in my current TeX Live installation. I wanted to save the list in a file. I tried using the "Edit>>Select All" option from the terminal. But using that I am able to save only a small sub-section of it. Is there a simple addition that I can make to the "list" command with "tlmgr" to make it print the output to a file?

Comment: What operating system are you running? Try `tlmgr list | grep '^i' > packages.txt` under Linux.

Comment: Sorry about that; I am running Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Then just use the command line below :)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Simply type the following command in a terminal / command prompt:

```
tlmgr list --only-installed > installed_texlive_packages.txt
```

which will save the list to a file called `installed_texlive_packages.txt`.

Comment: How can I install from it then? `tlmgr install installed_texlive_packages.txt`, or ``tlmgr install `cat installed_texlive_packages.txt` `` doesn't work.

Comment: The default data output format changed in newer versions of `tlmgr`. With TexLive 2020 and later you need to add also `--data name` in order only get the package names without additional information.

Answer (score 23):

Compile it with `-shell-escape` option.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,hmargin=3mm,vmargin=12mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12\relax%
\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\trimtok\detokenize{i}#1^^M{#1}%
\gdef\trimmer#1{\expandafter\trimtok #1}%
\endgroup

\newread\reader

\immediate\write18{tlmgr list --only-installed > installed-packages.txt}
\begin{document}
\tiny
\begin{enumerate}
\openin\reader=installed-packages.txt\relax
\loop
    \readline\reader to \data
    \unless\ifeof\reader
        \item \trimmer{\data}
\repeat
\closein\reader
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

For animated version, [click this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnHgn.gif) (only several KiB).

Comment: I love overkill solutions :-)

Answer (score 5):

In 2020, type :

`tlmgr info --only-installed`

to get the list of installed package. Then do whatever you want with the output (like putting it in a file with `> myfile.tx`).

`info` command replaces former `show` and `list` commands (tlmgr manual: "The former actions "show" and "list" are merged into this action, but are still supported for backward compatibility".)