# Where can I find the changelog of TeX Live releases?

Tags: packages, texlive, updating

I know that TeX Live 2013 is now in beta and that there are already some new packages. I would like to know where the complete changelog will be available, when the new version will be released, and also where can I find the changelog for version 2012, released in the past year.

Is there a specific page on the TUG site, here or somewhere else? I've searched everywhere but could not find a complete changelog?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I don't know if this qualifies as a Changelog, but you find the Subversion repository of TeX Live at http://tug.org/svn/texlive/

Comment: Related [How to print the list of packages installed on TeX Live to a file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56009/15717)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's say you had a more specific question, like: "what new LaTeX packages are there in TeX Live 2013?"

After TL2013 comes out and you install it side by side to TL2012, assuming you've not changed the default install directory, you could do something like this (UNIX systems only):

```
ls /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ > 2012list & ls /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ > 2013list
```

followed by

```
diff 2012list 2013list | grep -v "^---" | grep -v "^[0-9c0-9]" > difflist
```

you'll get something like this inside the file named "difflist":

```
< ascii
> ascii-font
> asymptote
> beamertheme-upenn-bc
> dvipdfm
> enigma
> esami
> ipaex-type1
> ltablex
> mnotes
> rterface
> snotez
> songs
> spath3
> tikzmark
> titlecaps
> uiucredborder
> vdmlisting
> verbatimbox
```

(this is the difference from the last TL 2012 update and the latest [2013 pretest](http://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html) release, if you repeat this same procedure after the TL2013 relase you'll get
the complete list of new LaTeX packages).

The `grep` stuff is used to remove some reference numbers automatically printed by the diff command.

Items marked with `<` are present in TL2012 but not in TL2013 (may have been removed, renamed, etc.); items marked with `>` are present in TL2013 but not in TL2012 (again, may be new packages, renamed packages, etc.).

If you also wanted to know what, e.g., new libraries that don't deserve a new directory have been added you could make the `ls` command recursive, like this:

```
ls -R /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ > 2012list & ls -R /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ > 2013list
```

again followed by the same `diff` command as before. If instead of LaTeX you want to know the new XeTeX additions, you have to point your `ls` commands to `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/xetex`, etc. You could also do a complete screening of `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist`, but that would produce a looooooong list, also because in TL2013 the content of the `texmf` directory has been merged with `texmf-dist`.

This is not rocket science and I'm not sure it also produces useful information for, e.g. ConTeXt.

If you have TL2011 installed you can do the same to find what packages have been added in TL2012.

Probably there are commands to do something like this in Windows also and directly in the SVN repository as well.

### Using a tlmgr based approach

as suggested by texenthusiast an even better result is obtained using the command `tlmgr list > <namefile>`. This is how I did it:

1. `tlmgr list > 2013list` with `PATH` pointing to `/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/`
2. change `PATH` to `/usr/local/texlive/2012/bin/`
3. `tlmgr list > 2012list`
4. (for UNIX) `diff 2012list 2013list | grep -v "^---" | grep -v "^[0-9c0-9]" > difflist`
5. (for Windows) `FC 2012list 2013list` (*not tested*)

In my test I restricted the search to installed packages only with `--only-installed` after `list` so to keep the list shorter. The result is:

```
< i adobemapping: Adobe cmap and pdfmapping files
< i ascii: Support for IBM "standard ASCII" font.
> i ascii-font: Use the ASCII "font" in LaTeX.
> i beamertheme-upenn-bc: Beamer themies for Boston College and the University of Pennsylvania.
< i ccicons: (shortdesc missing)
> i ccicons: LaTeX support for Creative Commons icons.
< i cmap: (shortdesc missing)
> i cmap: Make PDF files searchable and copyable.
> i context-cyrillicnumbers: Write numbers as cyrillic glyphs.
> i context-transliterator: Transliterate text from 'other' alphabets.
< i dvisvgm: Converts DVI files to Scalable Vector Graphics format (SVG).
> i dvisvgm: Convert DVI files to Scalable Vector Graphics format (SVG).
> i enigma: Encrypt documents with a three rotor Enigma.
< i epstopdf: (shortdesc missing)
> i epstopdf: Convert EPS to 'encapsulated' PDF using GhostScript.
> i esami: Typeset exams with scrambled questions and answers.
< i gmverse: a package for typesetting (short) poems.
> i gmverse: A package for typesetting (short) poems.
> i ipaex-type1: IPAex fonts converted to Type-1 format Unicode subfonts.
> i ltablex: Table package extensions.
< i mandi: (shortdesc missing)
> i mandi: Macros for introductory physics and astronomy.
< i metafont-beginners: An introductory tutorial for MetaFont.
> i metafont-beginners: An introductory tutorial for Metafont.
> i mnotes: Margin annotation for collaborative writing.
< i mxedruli: A pair of Georgian fonts.
> i mxedruli: A pair of fonts for different Georgian alphabets.
< i pfarrei: LaTeX support of a priest's work.
> i pfarrei: LaTeX support of pastors' and priests' work.
< i pst-node: Draw connections using pstricks.
> i pst-node: Nodes and node connections in pstricks.
> i rterface: Access to R analysis from within a document.
> i snotez: Typeset notes, in the margine.
> i songs: Produce song books for church or fellowship.
> i spath3: Manipulate "soft paths" in PGF.
> i tikz-bayesnet: Draw Bayesian networks, graphical models and directed factor graphs.
> i tikzmark: Use TikZ's method of remembering a position on a page.
> i titlecaps: Setting rich-text input into Titling Caps.
> i uiucredborder: Class for UIUC thesis red-bordered forms.
> i vdmlisting: Typesetting VDM in ASCII syntax.
> i verbatimbox: Deposit verbatim text in a box.
> i xetexko: (shortdesc missing)
> i xevlna: Insert non-breakable spaces using XeTeX.
```

as you can see it now finds also additions which are not in the `latex` directory (as `xetexko`, which is missing in the previous list). And now we also got pretty descriptions!

---

Or you could just subscribe to the CTAN-ann [RSS](http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/maillist.xml) Feed and [mail-archive](http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/maillist.html) :)

Comment: Great +1 , Have a look at [Xavier's `tlmgr` approach to list packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56012/15717) works on all platforms with TeXLive distro and can list uninstalled etc.. may be you can locate the tex distro directory using `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFDIST`

Comment: @texenthusiast cool! The output of the diff made with the command you suggested is even more informative! I'm updating my answer

Comment: BTW, I would recommend diff -u to get unified diffs, which look more readable to me.

Comment: @norbert may be an alternative but you'll get a much longer list (254 lines vs. 43 counting only installed packages) with also the packages that have not changed. I think the non `-u` list already contains redundant information (like small changes in description) so it's up to you. Just in case anyone does not know, if you use the `-u` option the `grep` part is not needed anymore.

Comment: Don't know the option by heart, probably -c0 to show zero context lines. And that can be even improved, by first only listing the packages without desriptions etc ;-) basic unix shell programming, about 10 lines max.

Answer (score 4):

The [TeX Live user guide](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#news) contains a section on the highlights that changed from one version to the next.

However it does not show which packages have been updated from the last version.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm most interested in new packages.

Comment: New packages are relatively easy to check: Just compare the contents of the corresponding folders on both DVDs. To determine, which packages were updated might be the real challenge.

Answer (score 4):

https://lists.dante.de/pipermail/ctan-ann/2013-April/date.html lists all updates and new packages for April on CTAN. If there is no license problem then all new packages will also be on TeXLive 2013

Comment: BTW: Where is the deadline, i.e. until when do I need to release new package versions so they will get its way to TeXlive 2013 DVD?

Comment: No clear deadline, but will be soon, so hurry

Comment: @norbert Would be Sunday (5th of May) soon enough?

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt: According to http://tug.org/texlive/, the 20th is a planned very final deadline.