# How do I list the available classes in my installation?

Tags: texlive, document-classes

I am using TeXLive in Linux and want to learn and experiment. How can I list available document classes in my installation?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: OK, good to know!

Comment: You can do this by a simple script which finds all files in the installation path with the extension `.cls`

Comment: OK, so there is no built-in command for this?

Comment: Related [How to print the list of packages installed on TeX Live to a file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56009/15717)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX Live maintains some text files where all packages/classes etc. are listed. The files are called `ls-R` and there's one for each main tree. In order to find all installed document classes in your main path you can do the following command:

```
grep "\.cls" `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFDIST`/ls-R > $HOME/allcls.txt
```

After this process you have a file `allcls.txt` in you home directory with all existent document classes.

Comment: The location may not be correct. For example, on my Mac `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFMAIN` gives `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf`, but you want `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist`.

Answer (score 1):

```
find `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFDIST` -name *.cls
```

and if you have also a local tree:

```
find `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL` -name *.cls
```

Comment: This is slow ;-)