# Transfer installed packages when installing a new TexLive release

Tags: updating, texlive-2017

Currently I have TexLive2016 with some packages installed via tlmgr.
Now I would like to switch to the 2017 release and I was wondering if it is possible to somehow install the same packages in the new release without having to look them up individually.

Partiularly, I was thinking about something like exporting a list of the installed packages and then installing packages based on that list in the 2017 release.

Comment: Untested: maybe you can combine https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56012/89417 with a bit of text editor find and replace to get a space-separated list of packages and then paste this list after `tlmgr` in a command prompt for your new installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the idea by Marijn in the comment, I used the following workflow:

1. (Before upgrade) Collect list of installed packages in text document ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56012/102094)):

```bash
tlmgr list --only-installed > installed-packages
```

2. (After upgrade) Iterate through list and install each package with new `tlmgr` – I use fish shell:

```
for line in (cat installed-packages)
    sudo tlmgr install (echo $line | grep -Eo "[[:alnum:]]+:" | sed "s/://")
end
```

Comment: The question became obsolete for me as I started using miktex (also on linux). However your answer looks good to me, so I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: Glad to read, thanks! Did your switch to miktex come due to the issue described above and did it fix it?

Comment: It kind of fixes the problem, as it supports on-the-fly installation of packages. So I don't need to worry about packages missing, as it will install it when needed (automatically or after confirmation). On windows I used miktex, and since that was not available when I switched to linux, texlive was the only option. So switching to miktex was more like getting back to what I was used to.