LaTeX equivalent to pipreqs
In Python projects, one can use the package pipreqs to automatically create a requirements.txt file, which lists all the project's dependencies. This file can then be used by others, for example, with pip install -r requirements.txt, to set up a working environment.
Is there a similar option in LaTeX?

For context, I am redacting my PhD thesis using LaTeX, and I plan to share it on GitHub. I want to ensure that others can compile the document without manually installing each required package. Additionally, the project includes original data in CSV format and TikZ figure-building scripts.
Ideally this tool should parse the whole code base and extract all the packages mentioned in \usepackage commands, but also check PGFPlots version for instance (i.e. the compat=1.18 option of \pgfplotsset). Similarly to the pip option, one should also be able to install missing requirements on the new user's machine...

Edit (18/04/2024, 8:00)
Some comments mentioned using bundledoc which can be used to bundle a whole LaTeX project into a single standalone .tex file, as described here. But this is not exactly what I asked for. I would like a way to generate a dependencies file on my side, so that others can use it to install the appropriate packages on their side. On the contrary, the bundledoc / arlatex approach produces a single document, a bit like distributing an executable with all the required .dlls, whereas I would like to tell the end-user which .dlls they needs to fetch from public repositories.
The snapshot / \listfiles path
Now, I found how to do the first part using either the snapshot package or the \listfiles command.
Using snapshot, adding the \RequirePackage{snapshot} in the preamble and compiling produces a .dep file that looks like:
\RequireVersions{
  *{application}{luaTeX}  {0000/00/00 v1.16.0}
  *{format} {LaTeX2e}     {2022-11-01 v2.e}
  *{package}{snapshot}    {2020/06/17 v2.14}
  *{file}   {preamble.tex}{0000/00/00 v0.0}
  *{class}  {book}        {2022/07/02 v1.4n}
  *{file}   {bk10.clo}    {2022/07/02 v1.4n}
  *{package}{geometry}    {2020/01/02 v5.9}
  *{package}{keyval}      {2022/05/29 v1.15}
  ...
  *{-------}{Document-specific files:}{----}
  ...
  *{file}   {thesis.bbl}  {0000/00/00 v0.0}
  ...
  *{file}   {3_back_matter/last_page.pdf}{0000/00/00 v0.0}
}

Using \listfiles, as mentioned here essentially does the same but puts it into the log savagely, for you to try and grab is as you can...
Now what?
Either approach yields a list of the used packages (after removing the document-specific files, that is). This list could thus be added to the project's repository similarly to the requirements.txt file in a Python project.
The question that comes next is thus how to automatically install missing packages from this e.g. .dep file (using the snapshot approach).
The issue is that - to the best of my knowledge - there is no unique package manager for LaTeX distribution, contrary to the ubiquitous pip for Python. For instance both TeX Live and MiK Tex have their own package managers, tlmgr and mpm, respectively, knowing that certain Linux systems might also be able to use system package managers such as dnf on Fedora to do so, see here (taken from there).
The original question may thus be reformulated this way: is there an user-friendly way for the end-user to install missing packages / dependencies for a LaTeX project given a .dep file?
Ideally, such an approach should be cross-distribution / OS, but even something working with only Tex Live and MiK Tex would already by awesome, since they likely are the most used LaTeX distributions.

Edit (18/04/2024, 11:00)
This second edits follows discussion in the chat and Marijn's comment below:

this question is a possible duplicate of this one and that one, even if they are not asked exactly in the same way (and don't mentioned pipreqs, a keyword that pythonic users searching for the same thing as I did might use - I certainly did before asking)
the short answer is both yes and no: yes because one can use some scripting along with snapshot's or \listfiles's outputs along with tlmgr to automatically install appropriate packages in TeX Live, for instance. No because this is not user-friendly, nor cross-platform, might require root access, etc.

That being said, in practice:

a novice user who installed a vanilla TeX Live should already have all the required dependencies (so they doesn't care), whereas
the black mage - a.k.a experienced or power- user - who installed a custom minimal LaTeX distribution should be able to install the missing dependencies by themselves, using only a .dep file (using greps and regex black magic and their preferred package manager)

In the end, I'll thus only include a .dep file containing only the package-related lines of snapshot's output and leave those with non-standard LaTeX installations deal with it.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The reformulated question is also a duplicate, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377233/transfer-installed-packages-when-installing-a-new-texlive-release, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494643/texlive-import-packages-from-older-installations?noredirect=1&lq=1, and questions linked from there.

MiKTeX users can use the automatic installation of missing packages. And tlmgr works for TeX Live on all platforms. And using a .dep file, e.g., with SuSE linux is also nothing a novice would like to do. And usually you also need root access (BTW: I never need root access to install TeX Live package, I just need to be member of group texlive.) BTW: texfindpkg supports both TeX Live and MikTeX. So you can, e.g., use texfindpkg install -f array.sty to install either the TeX Live package or  MiKTeX package that contains array.sty and also the known dependencies.
