# How to make a paper with zero margins and use the whole paper size for typesetting?

Tags: margins, fullwidth

Inspired by solution of @kiss-my-armpit in [How to print the list of packages installed on TeX Live to a file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56009), I decided to make a poster-like document to list all packages in a single page. So I made a large paper with zero margin. But the problem is that the text will cut at the right margin, `\sloppy` macro doesn't help in this case and causes some big white spaces at the end of each line at following pic shows. I want the text occupies the whole width of the paper.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=0pt, hmargin=0pt, paperwidth=34cm,paperheight=23.5cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begingroup
\catcode`\^^M=12\relax%
\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\trimtok#1^^M{#1}%
\gdef\trimmer#1{\expandafter\trimtok #1}%
\endgroup

\newread\reader

\immediate\write18{tlmgr list --only-installed|cut -d":" -f1|cut -d" " -f2-|grep -v x86_64-linux|shuf > installedPackages.shuf}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
%\sloppy
\noindent
\fontsize{6}{6.05}\selectfont\ttfamily
\openin\reader=installedPackages.shuf\relax
\loop
    \readline\reader to \data
    \unless\ifeof\reader
        \pgfmathparse{int(rand*9)}%
        \ifodd\pgfmathresult%
            \bgroup\color{gray}%
        \fi%
            \trimmer\data\ %
        \ifodd\pgfmathresult%
            \egroup%
        \fi%
    \repeat%
\closein\reader
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem can be demonstrated with the much simpler MWE: `\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=0pt, hmargin=0pt, paperwidth=34cm,paperheight=23.5cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
%\sloppy
\fontsize{6}{6.05}\selectfont\ttfamily
\lipsum[1-35]
\end{document}`

Comment: I think LaTeX doesn't know how to divide `plstmary` or `pictexsum`.

Comment: Also, no physical printer can actually print all the way to the edge of the paper, hence the option "shrink to printable area" used by the print driver.

Comment: @JohnKormylo You are right, but we can print on a bigger paper and cut the extra margins, as it happened in real publishing.

Comment: do you want the names of packages to be broken or hyphenated when they reach the right margin, or do you just want wider spaces between names in a line?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes got it. appreciate your concern.

Comment: @barbarabeeton As you know many packages have dash in their names, so in this case it's better to have wider spaces between names in a line. P.S. any solution with hyphenation is also welcome :D (I like to learn more)

Comment: @Ignasi I didn't get what you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean that it's difficult to insert hyphens in some package names.

Comment: @Ignasi Yes, but how can I set some extra spaces between words to fill the whole line with zero space at both side?

Comment: the approach i'd take is to use `\begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}` to make the lines break without exceeding the normal text width, and add some stretchability to the spaces in the monowidth font (they are usually a fixed width).  it will take me some time to check on how to do that; i know how to do it in plain tex, but there may be some differences in latex.  (maybe someone else knows how to do this and can answer more quickly.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Could you show me your solution in plain tex?

Comment: interword stretch is `\fontdimen3` and for `cmtt` fonts it equals 0pt.  for other cm fonts, the stretch appears to be about half the interword space (`\fontdimen2` -- texbook p.433), so if you want stretchy spaces for the monowidth font, it seems reasonable to set `\fontdimen3=.5\fontdimen2`.  the problem is, i don't remember whether such a setting is global or local, and haven't time to test that right now.  you can try setting it locally within the `\ttfamily` block, but it may persist after that if i've guessed wrong.

Comment: by the way, once you have stretchy spaces in a `\ttfamily` environment, you will/may no longer have good alignment except at the first or last "word" on adjacent lines.