# tlmgr install from a requirement file

Tags: installing, tlmgr

Is there a way to dump the list of installed package to be used as a basis for a new installation with `tlmgr` ? The same way `pip` works:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

then later, after a fresh `git clone`

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Note: This is not a duplcate from [How to print the list of packages installed on TeX Live to a file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56009/how-to-print-the-list-of-packages-installed-on-tex-live-to-a-file) because my question has two parts. One to list the requirements and one to install from that list, which is not answered by the former.

Comment: It's better to edit your original question with the explanation why it's not a duplicate, I'll comment there (and vote to delete this one).

Comment: @Marijn The duplicate notice above the previous question says: "If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one."

Comment: Ah yes, it does say that :) however, that is not really the best advice most of the time. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337015 for a meta-discussion on this subject.

Comment: On Linux or similar: `tlmgr list --only-installed > installed_texlive_packages.txt` (taken from the linked Q&A) and later on the new installation ``tlmgr install `cat nstalled_texlive_packages.txt` `` should work.

Comment: Which will limit the number of packages you can install because of ARG_MAX STRLEN. It's more a workaround than the actual answer to the question, but indeed it works and is more or less what I was going to do (`xargs`). The point of the question was to know if there was a proper solution. Apparently not, so that's what the accepted answer should be: You can't install from a file with `tlmgr`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer doesn't work on both my mac and linux (TL2021). Weird they have a way to export the list but no way to install from the list

Comment: @MinhNghĩa: the output format changes. You need to use now: `tlmgr list --only-installed --data name > installed_texlive_packages.txt`