# How to get an *up to date* texlive profile (e.g. from tlmgr command line)?

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

I read that by means of a profile it is possible to do an unattended install with the texlive installer exactly duplicating the package set that is present on another installation. I understand that it is possible to use this strategy to install a new version of texlive replicating a package set that had previously been arranged on a current (now becoming old) texlive version (possibly with minor adjustments).

With this, my question is how to get a *current* profile. Is there a `tlmgr` command to save the current profile (that is a profile that accounts for all the package installations and removals practiced after the original installation)?

Alternatively, I see that I have a texlive.profile in `/usr/local/texlive/2021/tlpkg/texlive.profile`. Is that meant to be an *up to date* profile? I see that the file has a date inside, but that date is not extremely recent (10 Dec 2021), and I am sure that after that date I have regularly updated my texlive. Does that file only get rewritten when an install/remove/autoinstall/autoremove action is performed during a `tlmgr` invokation? In other words is it possible that that file content is fully up to date regardless of the older date?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528069/tlmgr-install-from-a-requirement-file (see [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528069/tlmgr-install-from-a-requirement-file#comment1487205_528069) for the most recent command line flags).

Comment: An alternative is to write a small script that executes a single instance of `tlmgr` for each of the lines in the package file, in case there are many packages and ``tlmgr install `cat installed_texlive_packages.txt` `` exceeds the maximum number/length of command line arguments.