# Listing tlmgr packages installed in usermode

Tags: tlmgr

The question [How to print the list of packages installed on TeX Live to a file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56009/how-to-print-the-list-of-packages-installed-on-tex-live-to-a-file) asks how to list all tlmgr installed packages.

How can I list the packages installed in usermode, i.e. with `tlmgr install --usermode ⟨package⟩` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the answer is very straightforward:

```bash
tlmgr list --only-installed --usermode
```

I have no idea why I didn't try to do that last year.